# Phonegap Developer App returns 404

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, http-status-code-404

I'm very new with phonegap. After i installed phonegap, i followed steps on the [link](http://app.phonegap.com/).In my android device i'm trying to connect server but every time it says

> Error / Time Out!

On computer logs, it returns

> [phonegap] 404 /__api_ _/register

Then i tried connect on Chrome App i works fine and logs returns

> [phonegap] 200 /
>
> [phonegap] 200 /css/index.css
>
> [phonegap] 200 /phonegap.js
>
> [phonegap] 200 /js/index.js
>
> [phonegap] 200 /img/logo.png

i couldn't find anything about it. How can i fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

You need to update phonegap:
npm update -g phonegap

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.. I think it is a problem of the last update of the app :(

I try this:

https://www.robertkehoe.com/2013/01/fix-for-phonegap-connection-to-server-was-unsuccessful/

... but did not works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Update the app in your device and also in the computer with $ sudo npm update -g phonegap or C:> npm update -g phonegap

Comment: Although it is useful; looks its not exact answer. It should go in as a comment.